# Java Guice - use injection for specific instance?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I don't understand how can I use injection in Guice to specific instance. I tried this:

```
@Inject(optional=true)
    public void setCarpenter(@Named("setCarpenter") Carpenter carpenter){
        System.out.println("Assigned carpenter for Table");
        this.carpenter = carpenter;
    }


bind(Table.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("table1")).toInstance(new Table(4, new Metal()));
bind(Table.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("table2")).toInstance(table);
bind(Carpenter.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("setCarpenter")).toInstance(new Carpenter());
```

And it uses `setCarpenter` to both table instances. How can I specify to set to specific instance?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're probably looking for a solution to the "robot legs" problem.

See the wiki for details [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#How_do_I_build_two_similar_but_slightly_different_trees_of_objec)

Comment: I know this one. Maybe there is a simpler/prettier solution for this?